# Wait not working with IE

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, wait

I need to automate the following scenario:

A user connects to a web site and a few minutes later a div comes up with the option to click on a button to extend her session or to terminate it. If the user chooses to extend her session, a few minutes later the div will appear again with the same two options.

I first need to extend the session and when the div appears again I need to terminate it.

I have IE 11 installed on my machine and the following code works well with FF and not with IE. I cannot get IE to wait for the div to come and fails immediately with

> "org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on element (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 900 milliseconds"

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //Wait for waring (div) to come up
driver.findElement(By.id("ExtendSession")).click(); //click the 'Extend Session' button

new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until
(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ExtendSession"))); //wait for the 'Extend Session' button to  disappear

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //Wait for waring (div) to come up again           
driver.findElement(By.id("EndSession")).click(); //click the 'ExtendSession' button
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide the `html` of the target element?

Comment: Thanks Saifur, the problem was a IE hang.  See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh the DOM before the line that clicks the button

```
driver.navigate().refresh();
```

Comment: Thanks Roman, the problem was a IE hang.  See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my whole problem what the IE was hanging. I found my answer in the thread https://www.linkedin.com/groups/I-have-problem-in-my-961927.S.221787622

See updated code below

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                    ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//*[@id='divInactivWindow']"))
            );
            //  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ExtendSession']")).click();  --> I changed this line to the one below
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ExtendSession']")).sendKeys("\n");  //*** main change
        System.out.println("click Extend button once");

             driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.println("I did implicit wait");

            new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                    ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//*[@id='divInactivWindow']"))
            );
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='EndSession']")).click();
            driver.navigate().back();
```